# Computer Account Properties in Active Directory Domain using C#

Tags: c#, winapi, active-directory, wmi

I am searching to find a way to get computer account properties in Active Directory (AD) Domain using C#. I want to check the status of a computer in Active Directory (AD) like

1. its last scene in AD
2. how long it was not being log-in in AD
3. Who was Last Log-in on Active Computer and
4. If a computer is disable / enable in AD

Thanks in advance if you can help me, Cheers